# Include number of clusters in pymc3 mixture model sampling step

Tags: python, pymc3

Adapted from [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21005541/converting-a-mixture-of-gaussians-to-pymc3) of separating mixture of gaussians, I hope to include the number of clusters (mixtures) in the sampling step - assuming it is unknown.

This script works when the number of clusters `k` is known:

```
import numpy as np
import pymc3 as pm
import theano.tensor as tt

n = [500, 200, 300]
means = [21.8, 42.0, 62.7]

precision = 0.1
sigma = np.sqrt(1 / precision)

data = np.concatenate([np.random.normal(loc=mean1, scale=sigma, size=n1)
                          for n1, mean1 in zip(n, means)])
k = len(n)
with pm.Model() as model1:
    p = pm.Dirichlet('p', a=np.ones(k))
    means = pm.Uniform('mean', 15, 80, shape=k)
    sigma = pm.Uniform('sigma', 0, 20)

    process = pm.NormalMixture('obs', p, means, sd=sigma, observed=data)

with model1:
    trace = pm.sample(10000)
```

I tried a few different ways to sample `k`, but none worked:

```
with pm.Model() as model1:
    k = pm.DiscreteUniform('k', lower=2, upper=5)
    ones_k = tt.ones(k) #or ones_k = np.ones(k)
    p = pm.Dirichlet('p', a=ones_k)
    means = pm.Uniform('mean', 15, 80, shape=k)
    sigma = pm.Uniform('sigma', 0, 20)

    process = pm.NormalMixture('obs', p, means, sd=sigma, observed=data)
```

I got an error `TypeError: Alloc object argument after * must be an iterable, not FreeRV` at line `ones_k = tt.ones(k)`, apparently `tt.ones` expects an iterable not a pymc3.FreeRV as the argument. I appreciate any hint/suggestion. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The actual error message is about your usage of `tt.ones()`, which expects an iterable as argument: `tt.ones([k])`. However, this won't help you, as pymc3 does not support variables that change their shape during sampling. You could try to marginalize out the number of parameters and add the logp using a `pm.Potential`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I did realize that it is more tricky when the shape argument of a pymc3 distribution is a FreeRV. I will look into the pm.Potential you suggested.